# when does lambda begin to capture free variables?

Tags: python, list, lambda

In python documentation FAQ part, it says lambda expression begins to capture free variables when the function is called. And it gives an example as follows:

```
    for i in range(10):
        func[i] = lambda: 2 * i
```

when i is changed to 100, it gives 200.

```
    i = 100
    func[4]() # is 200
```

So, the i is accessed when func[4] is called where i has changed to 100, instead of any value of 0 - 9. This is the same for func[0], func[1], func[2] and so on. The answer is always 200, because i has changed.

But I recently wrote a following code:

```
    fs = [lambda x: x + i for i in range(10)]
    fs[3](10) # the answers is 19
```

when the function is called in the second line, there is no i at all in memory. Why the fs are still all x + 9?

Is it because the i is only captured when the scope of the for loop finishes, when i is 9?

Comment: "when the function is called in the second line, there is no i at all in memory" - there is. Local variables don't die at the end of a function if closures still need them.

Comment: Why are all functions have the same i as 9 in my second code? are the functions sort of 'share' the same closure where i is stored as 9?

Comment: Yes the i is shared. Lambda functions are being told to add the variable i, and the last place where i is set is the last number in range(10), which is 9.